# MySql error 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql

I have a simple function in mysql that doesn't like to work. I am extremely new to this so for me everything is hard now. I have 2 tables for a social network: users(data about the users) and friendship (here i have stored the friendship id between user 1 and user 2). I need a function that will count how many friends does user1 has. My code is the following:

```
Select count(idFriendship) 
from friendship
Where users.iduser=friendship.iduser1;
```

I receive error 1415. I have read other answers regarding this error but i could not find a resolve in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you can't return result set from function.  In function, you need to declar variable and fill it

```
Select count(idFriendship) INTO @1
from friendship
Where users.iduser=friendship.iduser1;

return @1;
```

you should be able to use function in some SQL, so only single value is allowed to return

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-udf.html

Comment: Thank you good sir. I just added DETERMINISTIC  to the top and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Sorin Have you used `SELECT... INTO`?